# javascript map in leaflet how to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

i have a basic geoJson program in javascript by using leaflet API.

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="india.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>


<body>
<div id = "map1" style="width: 1100px; height: 400px"> </div>

<script>

var area = L.map('map1', {center: [27.8800,78.0800], zoom: 4 });

L.tileLayer('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/raj333.map-gugr5h08/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(area);

var indiaLayer= L.geoJson(india, {style: {weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.1}});

        area.addLayer(indiaLayer);

        function clicked(){

        this.options.style.fillOpacity = 0.8;
            //how to refresh layer in the given map

        }

        indiaLayer.on('click', clicked);                
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is how would i automatically refresh the content of Layer on the map.

example here

```
             function clicked(){

        indiaLayer.style.fillOpacity = 0.8;
            //how to refresh layer in the given map

        }

        indiaLayer.on('click', clicked);
```

when user click on indiaLayer , the fillOpacity variable changes but doesn't reflect back on map which is understood since i am not refreshing the map. I don't know how to do it.

please help

P/s: these are the functions available on indiaLayer object (i.e. this object inside clicked function...which one to use for this purpose or there exist none)

You can check the list of methods available of GEOJson in the [Leaflef documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#geojson) This is the link to v.0.7.7, which is the closest available to used in this example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Last time I've used

```
map._onResize();
```

and that help me refresh map. Maybe a little hack, but, it work.

In your code will be area._onResize()

P.S: Maybe you should try change the way to set new opacity value - try change

```
function clicked(){
    this.options.style.fillOpacity = 0.8;
 }
```

to that

```
function clicked(){
    this.setStyle({fillOpacity: 0.2});
 }
```

Comment: just modified my answer. i hope it helps

Comment: However, i have one more query if you don't mind to look at

for example , i declared my geoJson layer as
var indiaLayer= L.geoJson(india, {style: {weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: '#F7BE81',
        dashArray: '10',
        fillOpacity: 0.2}});

Now if i want to access the first argument to the L.geoJson inside function clicked() ..like this way

alert(this._layers.22.feature.id); the firebug throws an syntex error ; missing. Can you look into it?

Comment: maybe there is a syntax error somewhere in your code. Anyway I can't tell anything without code. Try to create new question with source code, but I think you should carefully recheck your code before doing this.

Answer (score 20):

```
map.invalidateSize();
```

`map._onResize()` - it's a hack, and there is no guarantee that it won't be removed in future versions.

Comment: Actually invalidateSize won't work if the size of the map did not change. From the docs: "Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so"

Comment: My problem was in this sitaution:
My map was initially hidden, and when I displayed it, it was't initialized (not all tiles was loaded). After I have added this method call this problem was fixed. So I think that it makes some update anyway.

Comment: `invalidateSize` does not position open marker popups well when they are already open

Answer (score 0):

`area.fitBounds(area.getBounds());`

Comment: Op asked"the problem is how would i automatically refresh the content of Layer on the map.

example here

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Please read the question and the answer before reviewing.