# Creating a circle in leaflet without reloading the webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, leaflet

In android studio, I call a leaflet map through webview as follows:

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
     final WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(webview);

     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
     webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
     webView.setEnabled(true);
     webView.setClickable(true);
     GeoClient geo = new GeoClient();
     webView.setWebChromeClient(geo);
     String origin = "";
     geo.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, this);
     webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Map.html");

     return rootView;
 }
```

Now, I have a background service running that occasionally fires and I want a circle to appear on the map when this happens. To run the javascript function from java, the following would be used

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:fireCircle(" +
                    43.0000000 + "," +
                    -79.4000000 + "," +
                    300 + ",\"" +
                    "A CIRCLE!" + "\")");
        }
    });
```

where the leaflet javascript function fireCircle reads as

```
  function fireCircle(lat, lng, rad, textTitle){
      var circleColor = 'red';
      var circle = L.circle([lat, lng], rad, {
              color: circleColor,
              fillColor: circleColor,
              fillOpacity: 0.5
          })
      .bindPopup(String(textTitle))
      .addTo(map); 
  }
```

So far, the only way I've found to allow the circle to appear on the map is a complete reload of the webview page (onCreateView creates a new instance everytime). This isn't acceptable when a service is random firing.

Is it possible to fire the function without reloading the javascript page?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to re-reder the map after the fireCircle function runs.
Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515230/javascript-map-in-leaflet-how-to-refresh) tpic.
Short answer:

```
function fireCircle(lat, lng, rad, textTitle){
      var circleColor = 'red';
      var circle = L.circle([lat, lng], rad, {
              color: circleColor,
              fillColor: circleColor,
              fillOpacity: 0.5
          })
      .bindPopup(String(textTitle))
      .addTo(map);
      **map.invalidateSize();**
  }
```

Hope it works!